# How to define customized keyboard bindings in Xcode 4.6?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode4.6

I have defined/customized some keyboard bindings in Xcode 4.5 in order to give me a better typing experience.

Only the short-cut for `selectWord:` is originally defined by Xcode, others are added by me. They work fine in Xcode 4.5. But after I update the Xcode to 4.6, they no longer work except the `selectedWord` which is defined by Xcode.

The key binding file is at **/Users/jason/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings/Default.idekeybindings**

```
<key>Text Key Bindings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key Bindings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>@
</key>
            <array>
                <string>moveToEndOfLine:</string>
                <string>insertNewline:</string>
            </array>
            <key>^$D</key>
            <array>
                <string>selectLine:</string>
                <string>copy:</string>
                <string>moveToEndOfLine:</string>
                <string>insertNewline:</string>
                <string>paste:</string>
                <string>deleteBackward:</string>
            </array>
            <key>^$K</key>
            <array>
                <string>deleteToBeginningOfLine:</string>
                <string>moveToEndOfLine:</string>
                <string>deleteToBeginningOfLine:</string>
                <string>deleteBackward:</string>
                <string>moveDown:</string>
                <string>moveToBeginningOfLine:</string>
            </array>
            <key>~w</key>
            <string>selectWord:</string>
        </dict>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when Xcode is updated, the short-cut function defined by ourself will be overwritten by the default short cut function defined by the new version of Xcode. **In short, the short-cuts function defined by ourself will disappear, and we need to do it once again**.

1.I added back the following code into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` to define the short-cuts function again.

```
  <key>Customerized</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Insert new line in middle</key>
    <string>moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:</string>
    <key>Duplicate Current Line</key>
    <string>selectLine:, copy:, moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:, paste:, deleteBackward:</string>
    <key>Delete Current Line</key>
    <string>deleteToBeginningOfLine:, moveToEndOfLine:, deleteToBeginningOfLine:, deleteBackward:, moveDown:, moveToBeginningOfLine:</string>
  </dict>
```

2.Go to the key binding settings in Xcode, and type the new short-cut key for them.
[image]